# Jquery returns NaN,any idea?

Tags: jquery

HTML code:

```
<form id="hostadd" action="addmoney.php?taskid=12" method="post" onSubmit="return false">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="" />
current unit price:$
<input id="unitprice" name="unitprice"  type="text" size="5" maxlength="6" value= 0.50 />&nbsp
Shortfall:<input id="shortfall" type="text"  name="shortfall" size="4" maxlength="6" value=80 />
<input id="add_price" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Adjust()"/></form
```

Jquery code:

```
 function Adjust(){
        $totalprice=parseFloat($('unitprice').val())*parseInt($('shortfall').val());
          alert($totalprice);

        };
```

When I test

```
var unitPrice = $('#unitprice').val();
alert(unitPrice);
var shortFall = $('#shortfall').val();
alert(shortFall);
```

I got two blank alerts.

Comment: try var unitprice = parseFloat($('unitprice').val()), alert(unitprice)

Comment: And remember, you're not writing PHP! Use `var` to declare a variable with local scope.

Comment: Also, post the HTML, so we can see if you're selecting the correct inputs.

Comment: Break the code into individual parts and then walk through it with a debugger like Firebug. You should find pretty quickly which part isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for an HTML 'shortfall' and 'unitprice':

```
<shortfall></shortfall>
<unitprice></unitprice>
```

Do you mean to do this? Maybe your after a class or ID selctor?

```
$('.unitprice').val() //class
$('#unitprice').val() //id
$('.shortfall').val() //class
$('#shortfall').val() //id
```

Try looking at each individual component to see which is failing.

```
alert($('#unitprice').val());
alert(parseFloat($('#unitprice').val()));
alert($('#shortfall').val());
alert(parseInt($('#shortfall').val(),10);
```

Also, pass the radix to parseInt() (note: below I assume you are wanting decimal, so use 10)

```
parseInt($('#shortfall').val(),10)
```

Although the default is 10, its dangerous not to stipulate it. If a zero left-padded number gets passed then praseInt assumes Octal.

```
alert(parseInt(010)); // alerts '8'
alert(parseInt(010),10); // alerts '10'
```

Comment: Why do you assume he's using decimal values for 'shortfall'? :)

Comment: @Skilldrick: He's working with prices/currency, afaik no currency anywhere uses hexadecimal! ;-) I'd say it's a safe assumption although still unnecessary to pass the radix since 10 is the default anyway.

Comment: I didn't even notice that he wasn't using a proper CSS selector :P

Comment: Andy E: Although the default is 10, its dangerous not to. If a zero left-padded number gets passed then praseInt assumes Octal.

Comment: Incidentally, I bought a DVD for 10 Octal dollars yesterday and got 10 binary change from a 10 decimal dollar bill.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `$` function eats a CSS-like selector. So `$('unitprice')` looks for an element `<unitprice />`. But as you're working with HTML, there is no such thing!

What you mean to say is `$('#unitprice')`, referring to any element with the `id` `unitprice`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put alert there like this?

```
function Adjust(){
    alert([$('unitprice').val(),$('shortfall').val(),$('unitprice').val().length,$('shortfall').val().length]);
}
```

I believe one of the value might have non digits parts

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely grabbing an invalid value. Check the contents of unitPrice and shortFall:

```
var unitPrice = $('unitprice').val();
alert(unitPrice);
var shortFall = $('shortfall').val();
alert(shortFall);
```

Most likely one of these will be empty or show an invalid number.

Comment: Well, that's your problem. Read my above post.

Comment: Well, then either unitprice or shortfall don't exist, or you don't have values in them. You can check if they have values:
    if(shortFall)
    {
       // Your logic here....
    }
    else
    {
      // Do nothing? Tell user that he needs to provide a value?
    }